# Handling dependencies in Vue.js component published to npm

Tags: vue.js, npm, rollupjs

I am trying to publish a Vue.js component to npm. Everything works fine when I don't add any dependencies. But if I add for example `axios` and use its function, when I generate the `esm.js`, `min.js`, and `ssr.js` the axios code is not included in the generated `min.js` file. Even when I explicitly add it in `rollup.config.js`:

```js
const external = [
  // list external dependencies, exactly the way it is written in the import statement.
  // eg. 'jquery'
  'vue','axios'
];
```

Do I have to add all dependencies manually like this?

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-my-component"></script>
```

Comment: This is expected behavior. The code of external dependencies *shouldn't* be added to your package, because the code of your package should include just that– the code of your package alone. Anyone else that wants to use your package will need to use the same external dependencies, that's why npm tracks them in the first place.

Comment: @zcoop98, so the external array is just used when installing using `npm install`. right?